# Using :collection and :include_blank in Formtastic. How to do it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I use the superb Formtastic plugin for Ruby on Rails.

Does anybody know how to include a blank (option), when using a custom collection?

When I try:

```
<%= f.input :organizations, :collection => Organization.all(:order => :name), :include_blank => true %>
```

I get the select box with the collection, but NOT a blank...

Answer (score 22):

What kind of association is `:organizations`?  Does it work if you specify `:as => :select`?

There's spec coverage for the following `belongs_to` select, date, time and datetime inputs:

```
f.input(:author, :as => :select, :include_blank => true)
f.input(:created_at, :as => :date, :include_blank => true)
f.input(:created_at, :as => :time, :include_blank => true)
f.input(:created_at, :as => :datetime, :include_blank => true)
```

My *guess* is that organizations is not a `belongs_to` association, right?  If it's a `:has_many` or `:has_and_belongs_to_many` association, Formtastic will try to do checkboxes or a multi-select.  In the case of a multi-select, obviously it makes no sense to have a blank line in there (you just don't select any of the items).

Hope this helps, please post some more details about the models and associations in question.