# Formtastic - customise blank option in select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm using formtastic to generate a list of options in a select tag (eg. :as => :select) and I want a "blank" option, but this creates an XHTML warning (i.e. trimming empty

Looking at the source, it looks like formtastic is generating:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Is there a way to customise how formtastic generates blanks options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

maybe options :prompt could help you?

```
  form.input :organization,  
    :collection => Organization.all(:order => :title),  
    :prompt => "some text"
```

have a good day!

Answer (score 4):

Here are a answer with a similar issue :

[Using :collection and :include_blank in Formtastic. How to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110347/using-collection-and-include-blank-in-formtastic-how-to-do-it)

He say if you add a `:include_blank => true`, it will work... For example:

```
f.input(:author, :as => :select, :include_blank => true)
```

In my case, i have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, and automatically have a blank option.

```
f.input :groups, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => current_admin_user.groups.order("created_at ASC").all
```

I follow this guide : https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#the-available-inputs

I hope to help!